# Nginx HLS configuration

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming

I would want to configure HLS like that :

[Decrease latency](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/671)
(last message)

[CONF SRS HLS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v2_EN_DeliveryHLS)

But I don't find where is the location on that file or how to build that

(ubuntu, Nginx)
Thank your for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may not be ideal if you intend to provide a seamless playback experience with scrubbing/trickplay option.
One of the important recommendation in hls authoring spec is to have a closed gop structure. That means every segment starts with an iFrame. So if you have a gop size of 10seconds, it is better to have a segment size a multiple of gop size. So smallest one would be a 10 second segment. This would enable the video players to start the playback from a scrub/trickplay to a linear mode much faster than a non-closed gop solution. In a non-closed gop solution, you may have advantage to start the playback faster but may not be smoother experience combining other cases.